# Eclipse can't debug: what happened to my environment?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

When I run into debugging mode, the debug window shows the "white" screen, and cannot see the call stack. The picture is as below:
[image]

I have rebooted the eclipse and my computer. Still not resolved. Has anyone met this before?

Comment: Go to Window --> Reset Perspective and click yes. Try this.

Comment: still having this problem....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but i solved this the following way:

1. re-download the Android SDK(including eclipse) from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download
2. create a new work space

Then the problem is gone